# IShellFolder2.GetDefaultColumn aways fails with E_NOTIMPL

Tags: winapi, sorting, notimplementedexception

I'm trying to use the [IShellFolder2.GetDefaultColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to get the default sort column that is recommended for a specific shell folder. But unfortunately, the function always fails with `E_NOTIMPL` (HResult -2147467263).

The method call looks like this: 

`hr := ishellfolder2.GetDefaultColumn(0, sortColumn, displayColumn);`

The [IShellFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775075%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object is queried by using

`SHBindToParent`

or 

`ShellFolder.BindToObject` 

afterwards it's casted to an `IShellFolder2`.

The object is valid because it's successfully used for e.g. querying [GetDetailsOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775053%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Is there anything I`m missing?

Thank you and best regards

Comment: **Never** cast a COM interface pointer, use QueryInterface() instead.  It isn't otherwise clear whether your language runtime implements casting by using QI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Microsoft:

The reason why IShellFolder2.GetDefaultColumn always returns E_NOTIMPL is following:
Almost no shell folder implements this method. This means that this folder does not want to overwrite the defaut sort order. If this method succeeds, it returns a custom sort column that differs from the default sort column.